# how to redirect only the difference between two files using vimdiff

Tags: linux, vimdiff

vimdiff file1 file2

file2 content which is not present in file1 has to be written in new file, file3.

Is there any options for vimdiff to get this difference.

Answer (score 0):

within vimdiff you have the option *:TOhtml* to save the outpout as html.

Maybe you can use sdiff and colordiff instead

```
sdiff file1 file2 | colordiff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort files with `sort` and then apply `comm`